# Why is my Windows 10 randomly restarting?

Tags: windows-10, reboot

Custom built PC,
System info:
Edition: Windows 10 Pro
Version:    21H2
Installed:  ‎12/‎6/‎2021
OS build:   19044.1415
AsRock Mobo: B550M Pro4
Processor:  AMD Ryzen 3 3200G with Radeon Vega Graphics 4Core 3.60 GHz
Installed RAM:  16.0 GB (13.9 GB usable)
64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

No BSOD, no Events.
Running only 51 processes, all drivers are up to date and have been tested.
No overheating or overclocking.
Only one startup app, CareUEyes.
I had 3 yesterday, once while running Brave browser, (just surfing),
twice while idle and one early today, while idle overnight.

Comment: Try to look for messages in the Event Viewer. Do you have any recent `.dmp` files in the folder `C:\Windows\Minidump`?

Comment: Windows no longer shows blue screens. Type in *Settings* search *problem reports*.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response. No messages in Event viewer, I use WinDBG, no dump files or memory dumps. Problem reports was empty also. Complete scan with Malwarebytes, nothing.

Comment: Is it your power supply? Edit your question with exact symptoms. Windows has to be running to write a dump file (computers choose to crash to prevent data corruption). If the writing of the dump errors then you won't get one. Windows writes dump files to the page file as it knows where that is and it won't corrupt data. It transfers it on boot from page file to a dump file. You do have a page file on the boot partition (the one with c:\windows) of a big enough size?